# Call Html.ActionLink from a button?

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap

How can I call the "Register" ActionLink (The one generated on the standard MVC5 
project using VS2013) from a bootstrap button?

This is the original code:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Register", "Register", "Account", routeValues: null, htmlAttributes: new { id = "registerLink" })
```

I tried this but obviously it didn't work:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-info" onclick="window.location.href('@Url.Action("Register", "Account")')">Add New User</button>
```

Comment: Why you don't use an Anchor with the proper class? @Html.ActionLink("Register", "Register", "Account", routeValues: null, htmlAttributes: new { id = "registerLink", @class="btn btn-info btn-link"  }) should work and should be visibile as button too.

Comment: Perfect. It worked fine. I upvoted.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

```
<input type="button" class="btn btn-info" value="Let's Go!" onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("Action", "Controller")'" />
```

This should work fine...

Comment: Is it possible to open in new tab?

Answer (score 6):

```
@Html.ActionLink("Register", "Register", "Account", routeValues: null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "btn btn-primary", @role="button" })
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please note that first posts are thoroughly moderated to introduce you to the community. Please add explanation to your answer - why the line in the question doesn't work, and what did your suggestion actually improve.